# PHP : unable to insert json string into database

Tags: php, json

I am new to php. I am sending a json string in `post`. That json string is array list of products. which I will be sending from android to php webservice. When I var_dump my array after decode it shows null.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$servername = "mysql.hostinger.in";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_name";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$orderDetails = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['orderDetails']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$refNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['refNo']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
$amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['amount']);

$objs = json_decode($orderDetails, true);

//var_dump($objs);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblOrder (name, refNo, date, quality, design, qty, pcs, amount) values ('$name', '$refNo', '$date', 'mix quality', 'mix design', '1250', '2', '$amount')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$orderId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

if(is_array($objs) || is_object($objs)){
foreach($objs as $item) {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tblOrderDetails (orderId, quality, design, shade, quantity, rate) 
       VALUES ('$orderId', '".$item['qualityName']."', '".$item['designName']."', '".$item['name']."','".$item['pcs']."', '".$item['amount']."')";

       mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
     }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And here is my json string which I am passing as `orderDetails` in post.

```
[
  {
    "amount": "1000",
    "qualityName": "Cotton",
    "designName": "11001",
    "discPercent": "5",
    "image": "http://website.com/Demo/images/1.jpg",
    "name": "Black",
    "position": 0,
    "pcs": 3,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "amount": "900",
    "qualityName": "Cotton",
    "designName": "11001",
    "discPercent": "9",
    "image": "http://website.com/Demo/images/2.jpg",
    "name": "Green",
    "position": 0,
    "pcs": 2,
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

In android I am using Volley Library to send data in post.

Please suggest me something.

Comment: how is the JSON data being sent as POST data? e.g. standard form submission, AJAX request, etc.? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43984520/edit) your post to include those details.

Comment: it is send from android using `Volley Library`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you're getting on `$_POST['orderDetails']` is valid (assuming it is the string you posted at the end of your question).

However you're invalidating it with

```
$orderDetails = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['orderDetails']);
```

You should decode it first with

```
$objs = json_decode($orderDetails, true);
```

and then escape each property into the `foreach` loop when building the SQL string:

```
foreach($objs as $item) {
    $qualityName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $item['qualityName'] );
    $designName  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $item['designName'] );
    /* ... */

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tblOrderDetails (orderId, quality, design, shade, quantity, rate) 
       VALUES ('$orderId', $qualityName, $designName, ....... )";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
}
```

---

**Important note:**

It is highly reccomended to use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of escaping data and then building queries by joining strings.

They're trivial to use, code is more readable, less error prone and not subject to SQL injection.